# On aws-rds on aws-cdk, where is the setting to make database publicly accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

With AWS RDS, the console and the CLI/API both have a switch to make the database publicly accessible, but I cannot find a way to do this with the new aws-cdk using the constructs provided.  There is a boolean for this in the Cloud Formation classes (e.g. CfnDBInstance), but I can't find documentation on how to use that in combination with the constructs.  The CDK is pretty amazing, and it set up everything perfectly with just a few lines of code, except for this one piece.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whether the database is made publicly accessible or not is derived from the `vpcSubnets` prop which is of type `ec2.SubnetSelection`.

```ts
const instance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Instance', {
  ... // other props
  vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }
});
```

See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.62.0/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/instance.ts#L315

Answer (score 5):

For the python crowd:

```py
database = rds.DatabaseInstance(self, "Instance", 
        ... // other props
            vpc_placement=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC),
        )
```