# CDK RDS public accessible database

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I want to create a database with cdk that is publicly accessible (dev db). I know how to do it through the Web UI. I need to set the Public accessibility to true and allow my IP as Inbound on the Security Group.

```
        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Vpc')

        const postgres = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Postgres', {
            engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
            instanceClass: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
            masterUsername: 'postgres',
            vpc,
        })
```

this is my current status, it works fine, but no public access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On aws-rds on aws-cdk, where is the setting to make database publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221125/on-aws-rds-on-aws-cdk-where-is-the-setting-to-make-database-publicly-accessible)

Comment: part of it yes, I just need to figure out the security group problem. adding port 5432 from any ip

Comment: looks like postgres.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(5432)) does the trick. I'll post the full solution once im done

Comment: Glad you solve your issue :)

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Vpc')

        const postgres = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Postgres', {
            engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
            instanceClass: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
            masterUsername: 'postgres',
            vpc,
            vpcPlacement: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }
        })

        postgres.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(5432))
```

`vpcPlacement: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }` sets public access to true
`postgres.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(5432))` allows inbound traffic from port 5432

Comment: or even easier: postgres.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4()